# Rails 3 mountable engine missing protect_from_forgery call in ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

When a new rails app is created, its ApplicationController contains a call to protect_from_forgery. But when creating a mountable engine, the namespaced ApplicationController does not contain that call by default. What's the reasoning for that?